# Apache-NIFI - Suspend flow while revalidating the token

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the following situation:

I need to record several entries using a web service where I use a token that expires every 60 minutes for authentication. The service does not consider when the token was last used, when it arrives at 60 minutes I have to renew the token. I am using InvokeHTTP and when the `401 - Unauthorized` error occurs I need to validate the token. How do I suspend the flow while I revalidate the token?

Example: I have 3 entries to make. I managed to record the first one, and when it was recording the second it gave the authentication error. How do I revalidate the token, reprocess the second record and not let the third record process, while keeping it in the queue? I tried to use Wait, but it does not suspend processing, everything in the queue is processed.

Comment: where are you storing the token?

Comment: just an idea: run a separate thread that just renews token every 50 min without need to block any requests.

Comment: I am storing in a variable

Comment: after `401` reset variable value. before `invokeHttp` put `routeOnAttribute` to validate variable value and if it's empty then make a loop to itself.

Comment: create loop that is checking on registry variable thru an execute streaming cmd